# If Value Less Than 500 Add 100, and so on

Tags: excel

I want to generate values based on a condition statement:

If A1 is less than or equal to 500, then add 100
if A1 is less than 1000 and greater than 500 then add 200
if A1 is greater than or equal to 1000 then add 300

and so on.

How might I achieve this in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

You can start with following formula and improvise. *Not complete*

```
=IF(F6<=500,F6+100,IF(F6<=1000,F6+200,"do more"))
```

Here F6 is cell in worksheet.

Read IF method help for more details.

Comment: superb , really glad ..here is what i used based on ur solution

=IF(C2<=500,C2+100,IF(C2<=1000,C2+200,IF(C2>1000,C2+300)))

Comment: This was a quick solution, I am sure the problem can be solved in more easier way.

Answer (score 0):

Given "and so on", perhaps:

```
=A1+100*(1-(A1=500))+(INT(A1)-MOD(A1,500))/5
```